# Yii order/search related model in bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView

Tags: php, yii

there is 3 tables
article, author and university

I'm making a grid for table article. Every article belongs to one author and every author belongs to one university. I need to show University.name | Author.name | Article.*

At admin view

```
$gridWidget=$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'dados-cd-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'author_name'=>array(
            'name' => 'author_name',
            'value' => '$data->author->name'
        ),
        'university_name'=>array(
            'name' => 'university_name',
            'value' => '$data->university->author->name'
        ),
            ...
array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

And at article model I have

```
public $author_name;
public $university_name;

public function rules()
    {
        ...
        return array(
            array('author.name, university.name, ... ', 'safe', 'on'=>'searc

h'),
         ...
            );
    }
public function search()

{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->with = array( 'author','author.university' );

    $criteria->compare('author.name',$this->author_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('university.name',$this->university_name,true);

    ...

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                'author_name'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'author.name',
                    'desc'=>'author.name DESC',
                ),
                'university_name'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'university.name',
                    'desc'=>'university.name DESC',
                ),
                '*',
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

The grid is working perfect fine. However when I try to search or order by author_name I got a error message. I'll try to translate the error message from portuguese but I don't know if it is like that in english: "Undefined table:7 Error: missing entry for table author"

The funny part is that the university search and order is working just fine. And I can't see the diference between they.

Anyone can help me?

## Edited

I already checked if the column name in database is really "name"
At the error message it's showing part of the query is saying "(WHERE author.name LIKE ycp0)". I think this is the key of my prioblem but I dont know exactly how.

## Edited

Error message
Error 500:

## CDbException

CDbCommand falhou ao executar o comando SQL: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table:7 ERRO: faltando entrada para tabela "autor" na cláusula FROM LINE 1: ..."autor"."universidade_id"="universidade"."id") WHERE (auto...

^.The SQL statement executed was SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 't'.'id') FROM "artigo" 't' LEFT OUTER JOIN 'autor' 'autor' ON ('t'.'artigo'.'autor_id'='autor'.'id') LEFT OUTER JOIN 'universidade' 'universidade' ON ('autor'.'universidade_id'='universidade'.'id') WHERE (autor.nome LIKE: ycp0)

Comment: I've noticed you have spelt name wrong in your grid. `'value' => '$data->university->author->nome'`

Comment: Sorry Rowan, I tranlate the code to english, on original code  (portuguese) everything is "nome" "universidade" and "autor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!!

I use ' "table"."column" ' and works. I don't understand why it works withouth " " for university but is required for author. However I also put " " in university and is still working so I believe using " " is the right way.

Thanks for everyone who tryed to help me. The heaven belongs to you guys. <3

//sort

```
 return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'attributes'=>array(
                    'author_name'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'"author"."name"',
                        'desc'=>'"author"."name" DESC',
                    ),
                    'university_name'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'university.name',
                        'desc'=>'university.name DESC',
                    ),
                    '*',
                ),
            ),
```

//search

```
$criteria->compare('"author"."name"',$this->author_name,true);
$criteria->compare('university.name',$this->university_name,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit odd:

`return array(
            array('author.name, university.name, ... ', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),`

Rules for these attributes name should be in their own class, i guess. I don't think you can define validation rules for another model in a model Class. I think this will make Yii think there's a database column called 'author.name'.

Also:

you have this code:

`'$data->university->author->nome'`. Shouldn't it be `->name` ?

Add the error in your native language as you see it too, please.

Comment: Sorry I tranlate the code to english, on original code everything is "nome" Lol

Comment: But the on=>search defines witch fields can be searched, its not a validation I followed this tutorial 

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

Comment: I mean the rules() function. You should have attribute names, not things like 'foo.bar'.

Comment: Oh now I got it. I change from 'author.name, university.name' to 'author_name, university_name' but still got the same error.

Comment: era bom vc escrever toda a mensagem de erro para sabermos o que o Yii tá dizendo. < não sei se pode falar português aqui. =) Quando o Yii dumpa SQL na tela assim é pq tem algum erro no sql, tipo um atributo que ele não achou ou nome de tabela que ele ñ achou. Esse "ycp0" não é um erro, é só como o Yii constrói as consultas. Ele ñ põe as paradas direto pra ñ haver SQL Injection.

Comment: Desculpa demorar pra responder, a minha empresa não abre final de semana e eu fiquei sema cesso ao codigo. Como a busca é feita por ajax o erro está aparencendo em um alert. Eu digitei exatamente como veio. Vou colar lá. Obrigada